# How do I break out of this if and each statement?

Tags: ruby

I have the following where I want to output the first six users, and if there are more than six, just return '...'.

How would I do this?

```
<% users.each_with_index do |x, key| %>
   <% if key <= 5 %> 
    <%=x.name %>
    <% else %>
      ... <% next %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the last next for ? Next will just go to the next iteration. You need to use break if you want to go out of the loop.

```
<%
  users.each_with_index do |user, key|
    if key > 5
      concat('...')
      break
    end
    concat(user.name)
  end
%>
```

You could also

```
<%= users.take(6).map(&:name).join %>
<%= '...' if users.size > 6 %>
```

Comment: if index is a couple of thousand, will this iterate over all of them? I want a way to output '...' and break out of the iteration.